# MIPS putting characters into positions in a string is deleting the heap addresses of the string

Tags: arrays, assembly, heap-memory, mips, indexoutofboundsexception

So basically I have to insert characters from a character array to replace a null-terminated word stored in a heap. When putting the characters back however, they are added to the heap address fine but when checking in the next iteration of the loop the previous addresses are out of bounds. I have no idea why this is happening and any help is very much appreciated.

```
chars_to_word:                      # get characters from array and turn into word
    li $t0, 0                       # counter for loop
    la $s4, ($s5)                   # go to start of char array
    sub $s3, $s3, $t9               # go to previous address of heap (due to earlier increment)  
ctw_loop:
    beq $s0, $t0, print_string      # branch when end of char array
    la $t1, ($s3)                   # $t1 = word[i]
    lb $t3, ($s4)                   # load char from array to put into string
    sb $t3, ($t1)                   # put char into heap at index
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    addi $s3, $s3, 1
    add $s4, $s4, $t9
    j ctw_loop
print_string:
    sub $s3, $s3, $t9
    lw $a0, ($s3)
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j exit
```

For clarification, $s4 is the address of the character array, $s5 is the preserved start address of the character array, $s3 is the location of the string heap and $t9 is the common size of each part the heap and array.

The error occurs in print_string when trying to go back to the start position of the string heap to print, and it is an out of bounds exception when I believe it should just be where the start of the inserted characters are.

Thanks in advance and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `print_string` you are doing `lw $a0, ($s3)` which loads word (actual data, i.e. four characters) from address `$s3` and passes that as address to string to `syscall`, which obviously fails (you should see in debugger just before stepping over `syscall`, that `a0` doesn't contain string address, but something else; four characters of string are unlikely to form value which would resemble memory address into heap area).

Maybe you did want `la $a0, ($s3)` to copy `s3` into `a0`, but you can do that already one instruction earlier if you don't need to update `s3` itself: `sub $a0, $s3, $t9   # a0 = string address`